# Odd screen animation restoring app on iPhoneX

Tags: ios, ios11, iphone-x

When resuming an app (not launch), I get a little back and forth in the animation of what I assume is the previous state (the screen grab you see in the task switcher) fading into the current state.

I have taken out all the methods that happen when resuming and the animation still does this back and forth jitter. I have also looked at my storyboards and app settings to see if there was anything incongruous, and I cannot find anything. Anyone have any ideas? (I did a little slo-mo on the video for the relevant section)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQ6sOIHK8kQ

(I realize I may just not have the nomenclature to properly find this issue on google, so even that would be useful)

Comment: I get "this video is unavailable" - perhaps a permission problem?

Comment: "all the methods that happen when resuming" But you also might want to look at what you do when you deactivate or go into the background, because that's when the screen shot is taken.

Comment: @Undo fixed, silly oversight

Comment: @matt I only unsubscribe from notifications when resigning active

Comment: Could it just be an artifact on the simulator? On my machine the simulator can't even do an app rotation correctly.

Comment: @matt thats live capture from the X unfortunately =( It has been doing it since I got it, it was just really low on the to-fix list

Comment: I tried something and have narrowed it down I think - if I point the storyboard entry point at a blank viewcontroller it works fine - so maybe its an incorrect formatting on my part

Comment: I found the call thats causing the hiccup - view.drawHierarchy(in: view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true) - its the TRUE part that is causing all the issues, so I need to generate the image another way I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and will post the answer here to help anyone else who might run into this:

```
view.drawHierarchy(in: view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

This was being called in

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}
```

The code was used to generate an image from a view in my application. Oddly enough, this issue didn't crop up on previous iPhones - either speed or the completely different resume animation kept it from being an an issue.

---

Was asked for mode code in context:

```
func imageFromView(_ view: UIView) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0.0)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let snapshotImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return snapshotImage
}
```

Comment: Can you show a little more code? `drawHierarchy` draws _into the current graphics context_. It would be useful to know what the current graphics context _was_ at that moment.

Comment: Thanks. Fascinating. What did you then do with `snapshotImage`? Anything interesting? Did you put it into the interface? I ask because if not, it sounds like your code must inadvertently have been generating a new background snapshot, so that the _runtime_ grabbed it and displayed it.

Comment: I usually used it for flattening complex views for animation back when phones were slower. The place where it was causing issues was just to make an image of a color - and theres lots of other ways to do it, but I already had this method so it got used =)